# How to create lists from a list each like the original but with one item missing

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have 5 files in a list. I need to create lists where each file is left out once. Example:

```
drive = [File_1, File_2, File_3 , File_4, File_5]
new_list_1 = [File_1, File_2, File_3, File_4]  # leaving out File_5
new_list_2 = [File_1, File_2, File_3, File_5]  # leaving out File_4
new_list_3 = [File_1, File_2, File_4, File_5]  # leaving File_3
```

And so on. 
Thank you!

Comment: Man, you have to sort your question out. It is unreadable.

Comment: "I need to create a list..." - I guess that means, you have to write some code. If you have questions regarding your code, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Example code would help clear up the confusion. You call `glob` and then you want some lists... if you show that as python code and show the lists you want as python lists..., we can work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> l1 = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"]
>>> [[a for a in l1 if a != leave_out] for leave_out in l1]
[['f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5'], ['f1', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5'], ['f1', 'f2', 'f4', 'f5'], ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f5'], ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4']]
```

Comment: I’m sorry I did this from my phone. Thank you Mrlenny

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.combinations`.

```
import itertools
files = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5"]
list(itertools.combinations(files, 4))

# => [('f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4'), ('f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f5'),
#     ('f1', 'f2', 'f4', 'f5'), ('f1', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5'), 
#     ('f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5')]
```